# covariance of squared terms

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix

Assuming two variables
$X1$ ~ $N(0,1)$, $X2$ ~ $N(0,1)$

with $Cov(X1,X2) = a$.

Is it possible to derive analytically what the covariance between $X1^2$ and $X2^2$ would be?
Empirically (I tried this with large simulations), it appears that

$Cov(X1^2,X2^2) = 2*(Cov(X1,X2))^2$

I think this may however be just a coincidence because variables X1 and X2 have mean 0, and would in general love to derive this analytically.

Comment: "I think this may however be just a coincidence because variables X1 and X2 have mean 0, and would in general love to derive this analytically." So why not cut to the chase and set up $X1$ ~ $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $X2$ ~ $N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$?

Comment: it is as you suspect, there are two derivations here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668641/covariance-of-two-chi-square-random-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668641/covariance-of-two-chi-square-random-variables

as indicated by Chris Novak in comments about.

Thanks, this thread did answer this question, and showed a derivation (or at least how one is obtained in Mathematica)